# z-index conflict with static element

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lfzbzc5/2/

in here I am trying to make the notification box on top of the body class div but couldn't do it the logic says positioned elements should be on top of the not positioned elements but that isn't happenning

tried even making body class div relative and giving it z-index but failed too
structure of notification box is an absolute element in relative element in absolute element (for CSS animation issues)

HTML

```
<div class="notiIcon glyphicon glyphicon-globe">
</div>
<div class='notiAbs '>
    <div class='notiContainer'>
        <div class="notiBox">
            <div class="notiHeader">
                <span class="notiHeaderSpan">notifications</span>
            </div>
            <div class="notiBody">
                <div class="notiElement">Collaboratively enable high-quality imperatives before ubiquitous paradigms.
                </div>
                <div class="notiElement">Credibly productize customized services whereas.</div>
                <div class="notiElement">Efficiently embrace real-time markets without.</div>
                <div class="notiElement">Synergistically simplify collaborative web services.</div>
                <div class="notiElement">Intrinsicly evisculate magnetic e-services through.</div>
                <div class="notiElement">Holisticly build customer directed technologies.</div>
                <div class="notiElement">Phosfluorescently synthesize team driven strategic.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="notiFooter"><span class="notiHeaderSpan">See All</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="body">aasdasdasdasdasdasdas</div>
```

CSS

```
.notiAbs{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    overflow-y: hidden;
       margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 50px;

}
.notiContainer{
    position: relative;
}
.notiIcon{
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
        font-size: 25;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 10px;

}
.notiIconNumber{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    top: -10;
    left: -9;
    padding: 2px;
}
.notiBox{
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 4px 7px;

}
.notiElement{
    overflow-wrap:break-word; 
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-color: lightgray;
}
.notiHeader,.notiFooter{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 15%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.notiHeaderSpan,.notiFooterSpan{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.notiFooter{
        box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        cursor: pointer;
}
.notiHeader{
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.notiBody{
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: auto;
        height:70%;
}
.body{
}
```

Comment: where you want to get notifications can you say to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on top but the background is transparent so it makes the illusion that it's not. Just set a background color as follows :

```
.notiBox{
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-style:solid;
    background:#666;

}
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lfzbzc5/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Your notification box which I believe is the element with class "notiBox" is on top. The reason why it appears not to be is because it has an inherited background-color of transparent.

If you set the background-color property to say "yellow" (for examples sake) you will see that it is on top of the element with class "body".

Does that make sense? I can explain further if you need me to.

I've updated my answer as looking at your HTML again i've realised that the element with class "notiBox" is probably the only element (and it's contents) you want to appear on top